# vb.net There ia an error in for in loop. Can't declare it

Tags: vb.net

I don't know what's wrong with this, can anyone help ?

“tb is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level”
“cb is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level”

```
 Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        set_state()
        set_field()
    End Sub
 Private Sub set_state()
  Dim textboxes As TextBox() = {txtEventID, txtLocation}
        Dim comboboxes As ComboBox() = {cboStatusFrom, cboStatusTo, cboPtype, cboItemCode, cboDateFrom, cboDateTo}

        For Each tb In textboxes
            tb.Text = String.Empty
        Next

        For Each cb In comboboxes
            cb.Items.Clear()
        Next
 End Sub
```

I am a beginner and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots / image grabs. Post your code as formatted text.

Comment: Do you have `Option Infer On` in the project properties? If not, I think that code like that will assume that loop control variable is already declared. I suspect that adding `Option Infer On` at the top of the code file or turning it `On` in the project properties will address the issue. Without doing that, I think you might have to use this sort of thing to actually declare the variable in the `For Each` statement: `For Each tb As TextBox In textboxes`. The alternative would be declaring the variable before the loop: `Dim tb As TextBox`.

Comment: To complete @jmcilhinney's answer: [official documentation of For Each...Next, "parts" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement#parts).

Comment: Note that it's probably best that you learn what `Option Infer` does, rather than just turning it `On` blindly. It is `On` by default so, if it's `Off` for you, that must have been done explicitly. Some teachers will instruct that it be turned `Off` because they don't want students to rely on type inference. That's all well and good but the same teachers often don't insist that `Option Strict On` is used too, and it's crazy to insist on the former being `Off` without insisting that the latter is `On`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that each of the TextBoxes (txtEventID and txtLocation) and all of the Comboboxes (cboStatusFrom, cboStatusTo, cboPtype, cboItemCode, cboDateFrom and cboDateTo) exist and are accessible from your code.

The error is that tb and cb are set to each of those variables in turn and one or more of them is either "not declared or is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Maybe replace your code with this initially:

```
   Dim textboxes As TextBox() = {New TextBox()}
   Dim comboboxes As ComboBox() = {New ComboBox()}

   For Each tb In textboxes
       tb.Text = String.Empty
   Next

   For Each cb In comboboxes
       cb.Items.Clear()
   Next
```

that should run (but is of no use, of course). So then replace the new TextBox() with txtEventID initially and try again.  If that works, add in  txtLocation.

One of those should result in your error which will show you what you need to fix (make sure the Textbox is not Nothing, and is accessible. If control created in designer, make sure 'GenerateMember' set to true)

Do the same for the comboboxes.